# Trying to enable Virtual Machine Platform doesn't work

Tags: windows, docker

I need to enable Virtual Machine Platform in Windows Features to run docker. Whenever I enable it, there is a prompt to restart. But while restart I get the error:

> It looks like windows didn't load correctly.

I have to start windows in safe mode. And then the 'Virtual Machine Platform' setting is back to original. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you add some information? Like Windows version, full error messages etc.?